# Python tcp send receive functions

Tags: python, recv

In python the recv is a blocking function or not? I'm learned in the Uni C and there the was blocking and non-blocking socket. So I just wan to ask weather in python the recv function is a blocking function or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sockets in Python are blocking by the default. This behavior can be changed with [`setblocking`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) or [`settimeout`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

Another good place to find information on this is the [socket how-to](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html), especially the section on [non-blocking sockets](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets).

Answer (score 1):

The socket in Python is blocking by default, unless you change it.